# Laravel дублирование ссылки с /public и без (мое решение)

Tags: php, laravel, route

На продакшене недавно в вебмастере заметил что начали дублироваться ссылки:

Основная ссылка (пример): https://domain.ru/category/product/id

Ссылка дубль: https://domain.ru/public/category/product/id

При чем на локальном вторая ссылка сразу падает в 404, а на продакшене открывается как ни в чем не бывало, показывая контент как и в основной ссылке, совершенно без ошибок.

Гуглил, сразу убрал вариант с перемещением файла index.php в корень проекта. Вариант с изменением .htaccess мне вообще не помог.

Но я решил это так:

Comment: хост надо ставить на папку public а не костылями исправлять

Answer (score -1):

Создаем middleware: `php artisan make:middleware PublicMiddle`

Прописываем его в `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    ...

    'ispublic' => \App\Http\Middleware\PublicMiddle::class,
]
```

И в `routes/web.php` добавляем в группу:

```
Route::middleware(['ispublic'])->group(
    function () {
    // Ваши url
});
```

В созданном middleware `app/Http/Middleware/PublicMiddle.php` прописываем код:

```
    /* Разбиваем текущий url по домену, чтобы получить правую часть от него
        $explodedUrl = [
            'https://',
            '/public/category/product/id'
        ]
    */
    $explodedUrl = explode('domain.ru', $request->url());

    if (isset($explodedUrl[1])) {
        // Если url разбился по домену, то правую часть ([1]) разбиваем по /
        $urlArr = explode('/', $explodedUrl[1]);
    }

    // [0] будет пустой, поэтому если [1] равен public, то выкидываем 404
    if (isset($urlArr[1]) && $urlArr[1] == 'public') {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $next($request);
```

Таким образом каждый url из вашего web.php будет проверятся на наличие в начале сразу после домена /public.